# How to ignore node with sub nodes in JsonAssertions?

Tags: java, assertion, assertj, jsonunit

I am using net.javacrumbs.jsonunit.assertj, JsonAssertions, assertThatJson to compare two jsons. I need to ignore node with array and sub-nodes. So in this example I would like to ignore all in node "ignoreAllIn"

```
  {
    "md": {
      "i": "value1",
      "z": [],
      "ignoreAllIn": [
        {
          "t": "1",
          "i": [
            {
              "j": 4,
              "q": 13,
              "v": "null"
            },
            {
              "j": 4,
              "q": 11,
              "v": "null"
            },
            {
              "j": 4,
              "q": 143,
              "v": "null"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I tried with wildcard *

```
.when(path("md.i[*]"), then(IGNORING_EXTRA_FIELDS))
.when(path("md.i[*]"), then(IGNORING_VALUES))
.when(path("md.i[*]"), then(IGNORING_EXTRA_ARRAY_ITEMS))
```

But I need to list all fields and the real number of nodes is too big to list.